# Best way to make regular EBS backed EC2 instance backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, disaster-recovery

**Problem:**

I am trying to find a way to develop a disaster recovery solution for a web application (with database installed on `EBS`, instead of `RDS` due to cost saving reasons), installed on a single `EC2` instance. Because the database is on the instance itself, I can't use a load balancer as effectively as I could have had the database been on `RDS` (stale data).

**Current DR strategy: manual weekly backups**

Until now I have been manually doing weekly backups of my `EC2` instance by making an image of the instance. That produces an `AMI`, plus one `EBS` snapshot for each attached volumes. (*note*: I am hoping that the snapshots made are incremental, can anyone confirm this for me?)

**Going Forward, suggestions needed:**

I will be automating the weekly backups using `Lambda`, but it seems in case of a disaster, I won't be able to bring the service back online quickly. I would have to restore the snapshot to a volume, and then launch an instance from the `AMI`, and attach the volumes to the new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes EBS snapshots are incremental.
2. If you are creating an AMI, that automatically creates EBS snapshots and associates those snapshots to the AMI. If you create a new instance from an AMI it will use those EBS snapshots to create the volumes for the new instance. So if you are creating an AMI you do not need to restore the EBS volumes from snapshots first and then attach them to a new instance, you simply spin up a new instance from the AMI and it will have everything the previous instance had at the moment you created the AMI.

I highly suggest stepping through this once to verify for yourself that it all works as expected.

Comment: More on #1 above: could I ensure that the snapshots are "linked" to each other incrementally? I was reading this and thought if I could: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html#how_snapshots_work

Comment: You can't really as far as I know. If the snapshots are taken from the same volume then you have to trust that they are incremental. If you want to ensure your snapshots are incremental you could add up the total "size" of each snapshot in your account, and then verify that in your monthly bill you are being charges for less than that total amount of EBS snapshot space.